# Get the master identity of a GIT commiter / author received from TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi client

Tags: git, tfs

We're creating an app that gathers up commits made by certain people for a given month and archives them.

To achieve this the TFS client from the `TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi` namespace is used. It works fairly well when it comes to finding the changes made (it finds both TFS and GIT changes), but there's a small bit of trouble with some of the result details (specifically GIT results and the `GitUserDate` class). The results seem to have the locally specified GIT usernames. Since those are unreliable we would need to map these to the actual domain-names for the users who made the final commits to the server. In general there should only be a single author of each commit (the chance that someone had multiple authors working on a local repository before a commit to the server is made is extremely small).

I know this information should be in the TFS; there's an `IdentityMap` table in the TFS SQL database which **seems** to hold the information we're looking for. But we'd rather get this information through an API, as direct database access for this feels... wrong.

Is there a way to get this information from the TFS API?

PS. For the sake of completeness: we're using an on-premise TFS.

EDIT: Here's a code sample:

```
var criteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria();
criteria.FromDate = startDate.ToString();
criteria.ToDate = endDate.ToString();
var commits = gitClient.GetCommitsBatchAsync(criteria, repository.Id).Result;
var itemList = new List<GitFile>();
if (commits.Select(x => x.Committer.Name).Count(x => users.Contains(x)) > 0)
{
    foreach (var commit in commits)
    {
        var changes = gitClient.GetChangesAsync(commit.CommitId, repository.Id).Result;
        foreach (var change in changes.Changes)
        {
            if (change.Item.GitObjectType == GitObjectType.Blob)
            {
                var item = new GitFile  //this is a custom model class to help processing
                {
                    Committer = commit.Committer.Name, //commit.Committer.Email was also attempted
                    Date = commit.Committer.Date,
                    RepositoryId = repository.Id,
                    RepositoryName = repository.Name,
                    FileName = change.Item.Path,
                    Item = change.Item
                };
                itemList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    if (itemList.Count > 0)
    {
        ProcessGitFiles(itemList, startDate, users);    //users is a list of internal user domain names for whom files needed to be processed and saved
    }
}
```

Some examples of what's wrong: the `users` list contains domain names from the server and that is something we can rely on. The `Commiter.Name` (or `Commiter.Email`) are the local values as specified by someone's `git config` and in at least one case the name contained a typo, while in other cases the email was an aliased email address (normally a user at our company would use the format `jdoe@domain` but emails also have an alias format `john.doe@domain`).

Comment: Can you share exactly how you get the commits?

Comment: Also, can you provide an example to the local username that you got and what the "real" user name that exist on the server?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Example added including a somewhat generic example of the issue we're facing.

Comment: In the TFS, do you see the local name/email or the "real" name/email?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk In the TFS web UI the local email / names are displayed. BUT I've poked around in the TFS SQL database, and there seems to be a table with local-master identity mappings, as described by my question.

Comment: I don't think you can get this info with the API.

Comment: Would you be able to query Active Directory like using System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher in .NET?

Comment: @m00nbeam360.0 Query for what? I need to map the personal commit details (username / email) that people specified in GIT and it's TFS that should have the mapping data. What would I be looking for in AD? Just because someone wrote a (valid) aliased email doesn't make this information any more reliable without the TFS mapping...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use the push rather than the commit.  The commit is just a record of the information that Git tracks for commits.  The Push and/or Pull Request have TFS user based identities for who created them.

Comment: While this is true, a single push / pull can have multiple commits, and the application being developed has to make a backup of the changes made by specific people for a given month. This means this information doesn't have the required granularity. Additionally, while a user will likely only push their own changes from their machine onto the TFS server, the branch might then get pulled into something worked by many. Anyway, I'll double check if the push / pull information could be enough.

Comment: The push is the only point that I know of that has the authenticated information accessible in the API, though it lists the commits in the push.  The only other alternative is to put a push hook that verifies the committer information of the commits before allowing the push.  We actually do this in our environment, but that's a pretty poorly documented process and requires a dll be added to the plugins folder and requires an iis restart for updates to the hook.

Comment: Alternately, the GitCommit does appear to have a link to the push that originated it.